# Scrapy CrawlSpider Not Crawling

Tags: python, html, mongodb, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm currently building a spider to extract musical instruments and their data.

For this I am using CrawlSpider, and the end result would be to take all of this data and place it into mongoDB documents by model name. I am not finished, obviously, and have not gotten to this point.

**EDIT: I was able to fix the error and get it running:but now the crawler crawls '0' pages and returns no data into the csv file it outputs. What could the problem be?**

Here's what I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item


class FenderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "fender"
    allowed_domains = ["example.org/"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.org/fender/?ob=model_asc#results',
    )

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\&pn=*', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):

    item = scrapy.Item()
    item['data'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="itemResult"]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

Here is my Items file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy

class MdbItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    name = 'MdbItem'
    Item = scrapy.Field()
   # company = scrapy.Field()
   # model = scrapy.Field()
   # model_name = scrapy.Field()
    #instrument_type = scrapy.Field()
   # year = scrapy.Field()
   # serial = scrapy.Field()
   # sku = scrapy.Field()
```

Everything is working properly, but no data is extracted. I don't understand why.

Can anyone help? 
I am just learning both Python and Scrapy so am very much a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `scrapy.CrawlSpider` with `CrawlSpider` which is already imported from `scrapy.contrib.spiders`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this completely fixed that problem. Now however I am left with a new one- the crawler does not seem to be crawling or extracting data. (ignore edits made to answer above, this was accidental and meant to be a comment)

Comment: @page this is a separate problem and should be addressed in a separate question. You should not have edited the question completely - this is not how things work here.

Comment: Okay, I apologize. Will create a new question.